# Expression of sum in floating point system

Tags: numerical-calculus, floating-point, rounding-error

This is a question of an exam on Numerical Analysis I had:

*Consider the floating point system of base $2$, maximum number of decimals $53$, maximum exponent $1025$ and minimum exponent $-1022$. That is, the numbers in this system are of the form
$$0.d_1d_2\ldots d_{53}\cdot 2^{e},\ -1022\leq e\leq 1025.$$
Calculate the value of the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{1021}\frac{1}{4^k}$$
in this number system if we round it up and if we truncate it.*

**My attempt:**

We have that $(1/4)_{10}=0.01_2$, where the subscript means the base used. Therefore, the sum in this floating number becomes
\begin{align*}
1_{10}+(1/4)_{10}+(1/4^2)_{10}+(1/4^3)_{10}+\cdots&=1_2+0.01_2+0.0001_2+0.000001_2+\cdots\\
&=1.01010101\ldots_2\\
&=0.1010101\ldots 010\color{red}{1}\cdot 2^1.
\end{align*}
I think $\color{red}{d_{53}}=\color{red}{1}$ because the $1$'s are in the odd digits (and $53$ is odd). Since the following $1/4^k$ that doesn't add to the sum has a $1$ in the $55$th decimal, it makes no difference if we round up or if we truncate the sum.

**Is my approach correct? Thanks!**

Comment: I find the wording of this problem a bit ambiguous. Do we sum in true arithmetic, then round, or round to the system, then sum? But in any case I fail to see how it makes no difference between rounding up and truncating. Truncating for integers means that any $x$ with $0 < x < 1$ is taken to $0$. "Rounding up" is the opposite: $x$ is taken to $1$. $1/4^{28}$ is greater than $0$. So "rounding up" means it is increased in value to something representable with 53 digits. I.e., adding it in gets you to $0.101\dots 0110\times 2^1$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, my understanding of these definitions is that $2^{-54}$ is truncated to $0$ and that $2^{-54}$ is rounded up to $2^{-53}$ (and numbers smaller than $2^{-54}$ are ignored). That is, the definition I have for these procedures only cares about the following digit to the maximum one represented in a floating point system.

Comment: Well, the real question is not what is your understanding or what is my understanding, but what is the understanding the person giving the test. That is only one who can accurately answer your question. If you do not know for a fact that your concept is the one they mean, then I suggest you ask them for clarification.